# Multiple Accounts on 1 email - Multisite

Tags: plugins, multisite

It seems like that on my Multisite I would want multiple accounts to be created from a single email. I have already tried the Allow Multiple Accounts plugin but yeah that does not work.

Any solution on how to implement this? Thanks for all the help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should rethink what you are trying to do as an email address represents with no ambiguity a specific user. Getting many users to be identified by one email can create problems as to who gets to set the password.

In general if it a small amount of accounts it is probably easier to create unique email addresses for each of the accounts and just forward the emails from there to one specific email.

Comment: Well actually we already put some limits in place so that those that are registering on the multisite are part of our registered members so there should be no problem with like anonymous registrations. So 1 email will = 1 user but then that user will have capabilities to create multiple sites on the network. Thanks

Comment: there is no problem with one user having several sites or having permisoin to admin and edit content in several sites, it is part of the built-in functionality of the network.

Comment: I think as long as they are logged in to their account right, they would be able to create a site when they go to /wp-signup.php?

Comment: yes they will, system is really designed for it